# You have to consider all the probabilities (A comparison between possibility and probability / likelihood)

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-usage, sentence-request

We know that:

Technically, possibility of any event is always 1 or 0 i.e. 'yes'  or 'no'. If an event is possible, how likely will its occurrence be,  under a given situation is probability.

Example, When we roll a dice, possibility of it showing up number 5 is 'Yes' (or 1) possibility of showing up  number 8 is 'No'(or 0).In a situation where the dice is rolled once, Probability of it showing up number 5 is 1/6.

So, every event that we consider while finding the probability of occurrence of a particular event, is a possible event.

Now let's suppose you are giving an advice to someone who needs to look at the matter from the outside and there are some hidden aspects of the matter they are dealing with which are not visible for them and you intend to explain and clarify them the way the have to take and the steps they have to go through. You say:

> - You should consider all the aspects of the matter prior to making any decision. **You have to consider all the probabilities / likelihood.**

What causes doubt in my mind about the bold statements above are the [nearly null results](https://www.google.com/search?q=Conjecturally%20vs%20by%20guess&rlz=1C1NHXL_enIR722IR722&oq=Conjecturally%20vs%20by%20guess&aqs=chrome..69i57.3161j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22You%20have%20to%20consider%20all%20the%20probabilities.%22&*) I get when I search them on the net / [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=consider%20all%20the%20likelihood&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) again.

I was wondering if you could help me out with this case? I know I can say something like:

> - You should consider all the possibilities.

but is it possible to say:

> - You should consider all the probabilities / likelihood.

If not, then why?

Comment: _Possibilities_ is your word.

Comment: Just FYI, "You should consider all the likelihoods" is not wrong. In fact, all three are fine and in a piece of text, they might all be used interchangeably to avoid repetitiveness.

Comment: Since you want to emphasize to consider all things that _might_ happen _possibilities_ is a better choice I think. As a rule of thumb "_probability is bigger than possibilty_" the movie **in pursuit of happiness** :-)

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang "You must consider all the likelihoods" may not be ungrammatical, but it's unidiomatic. No native speaker would phrase it that way. Most people would say "consider all the possibilities", and if we were talking about something more technical and mathematical, something like betting on a horse race, "you have to consider all the probabilities", because there the probabilities are specific, concrete things to be considered. But that's a much less common situation. Safest and most idiomatic is "consider all the possibilities".

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang I am native speaker, and I *do* say no native speaker would put it that way, and that it *is* unidiomatic. If you don't believe me, maybe you'll believe Google nGrams: this phrase [hasn't even appeared once](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=consider+all+likelihoods&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) in all the books it indexes, going back centuries. The phrase "consider all likelihoods" is grammatically possible, as is "invisible green ideas sleep furiously", but they should both be avoided.

Comment: Some of the discussion here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55274/discussion-on-question-by-a-friend-you-have-to-consider-all-the-probabilities-a). I think that while it's a good discussion, it's starting to distract from the question a little bit.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang - Sorry, but you're dishing out bad guidance here. Check out [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=consider+all+the+likelihoods%2Cconsider+the+likelihood%2Cconsider+all+the+possibilities&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3). We can "consider the likelihood," we can "consider all the possibilities," but, generally speaking, we don't "consider all the likelihoods."

Comment: It isn't technically wrong because it could refer to the situation you describe.  However the only time someone would refer to considering the probabilities would be in  a discussion of analytical methods for a statistics-related problem.  In considering the possibilities, you would weigh the probabilities, so it is sort of implied.

Comment: @J.R.. as I had said in my initial comment, I had only offered it as an alternative to using the phrase "consider all the possibilities" repetitively. I agree, "consider all the possibilities" is the most common and probably what I would say myself. As the OP himself had mentioned, he had already known which one was the most idiomatic as well. He had just wanted to know if the other two were likely and probable possibilities (:D) to which I had responded with the sentiment of, "Yes, they're fine, if you want to avoid repetition."

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang - But as others have been telling you, it's **not** fine. When someone on ELL assures a learner that a wording is "fine," that doesn't just mean it's grammatical; it means it's idiomatic speech that wouldn't make the speaker sound non-fluent. Fact is, [_likelihood_ is seldom used in the plural](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+likelihood%2Cthe+likelihoods&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), and others have rightfully called you out for dispensing faulty guidance in this case. "Used interchangeably" my foot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You should consider all the aspects of the matter prior to making any decision. You have to consider all the **possibilities**.

You wouldn't use *probabilities* or *likelihood* since you have not stated any individual "aspects" in your statement. Also as a group of several probable/likely occurrences, use *possibilities*. For example:

> It is **likely** that yelling at your boss will get you fired, but you should consider all (of) the **possibilities**.